# How many time does the model train if I use 5 k-fold in R?

Tags: r, cross-validation, k-fold

```
ctrlspecs <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 5, repeated = 5)
```

I used repeatedcv method and set number as 5 and repeats as 5.
number=5. Does this mean 5k-fold?
If then, I think the number of the model trained and tested is 5. Is it correct?

I also set repeats as 5. Does this mean trainControl will be repeated by 5 times?

Does this mean the total number of train and test is 25?

Comment: What libraries are you using, caret?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, below I tried to explain the concept of k-fold and repeated k-fold cv. When you set k = 5 in k-fold cv, it will randomly partition the sample into 5 groups/clusters (with roughly equal size), and then predict 1 group each time by training other 4 (k-1) groups. The final prediction performance will be the average of 5 predictions. In repeated k-fold cv, it will repeat the k-fold cv described above for the times you set. Now back to your question, numbers = 5 will do 5-fold cv and repeated = 5 will repeat 5-fold cv for 5 times. In total, your final result will be the average of the 25 predictions (5 x 5). This is a documentation associated with this package which might be useful (e.g., section 5.3) https://topepo.github.io/caret/model-training-and-tuning.html#model-training-and-parameter-tuning.